# Assign function result to variable

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function:

```
function validateVip(){ 
    $("table[id=table-pss] tbody tr").each(function() {
        var keval = $(this.cells[4]).find('input');
        var data = $(keval[0]).val();
        console.log("result: " + data);
        console.log(data.includes([vip]));
        var x;                      
        if ((data.includes([vip])) == true)
        {
            x = "yay";
            console.log("Vip Exists");                          
        }
        else
        {
            x = "nay";
            console.log("No VIP");
        }                       
        return x;
  });
}
```

Whenever I call it, it always return "undefined".
Here is how I call the function `validateVip`:

```
var isVip = validateVip();
            console.log("is vip:" + isVip);
```

Can someone show me what I did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: At least you forgot `return` statement in your `validateVip()` function

Comment: Why are you putting `vip` in an array when you do `data.includes([vip])`?

Comment: @Barmar because I have a list of VIP in array and need to campare it whether html table has vip list in it. I just need a variable to notify if vip exists or not.

Comment: If `vip` is already an array, and you want to know if `data` is in it, it should be `vip.includes(data)`

Comment: `data` is a string, it can't include an array.

Comment: thank you @VasylMoskalov with your suggestion and combined with MaximeHelen answer it's finally return the desired value

Comment: @Barmar big thanks to you, you saved me from the future problem, yes that how I should do to compare the array. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of x is returned by the callback passed to `$().each`, which does nothing

You need to define the variable `x` in the upper scope:

```
function validateVip() {
    var x;
    $("table[id=table-pss] tbody tr").each(function() {
        var keval = $(this.cells[4]).find('input');
        var data = $(keval[0]).val();
        console.log("result: " + data);
        console.log(data.includes([vip]));

        if ((data.includes([vip])) == true) {
            x = "yay";
            console.log("Vip Exists");
        } else {
            x = "nay";
            console.log("No VIP");
        }
    });
    return x;
}
```

Note that `x` will be equaled to the last item assignment, iterated using `each`